# Where to create file in android device

Tags: android

I have a requirement that I need to create text file in to my device internal memory and write some data into the file.

For that I am creating file by reading the path "getFileDir()".

This is working fine in most of the devices , but in few devices I am getting "Permission denied" issue while creating file at the above path.

Can anyone please suggest me in which path I have to create a file so that this path accessible in all the devices..??

I am creating file in my onCreate() method of my activity.

I do not want to create file SD card.

Answer (score 0):

```
String APP_DATA_DIR = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
```